# What's the best tutorial for iPhone development, sans Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone

I tried out Interface Builder, but I'd prefer just to write the code. I understand this is reasonable and many iPhone developers don't use IB.

Does anyone know any good tutorials/resources about this?

All I have found so far is this video: http://www.vimeo.com/3363949

Comment: I'm not sure that approach is the best way to start off iPhone programming. I've found that anything beyond a non-trivial single screen app is best created in IB.

Regardless, I posted an answer below - the best way is to find out for yourself!

Comment: I'd agree with Justicle. I think a lot of iPhone programmers currently don't use IB because the original version lacked some iPhone-specific features that made it hard to use. The version included with SDK 3.0 is pretty nice though - and you should really give it a shot. It can take hundreds of lines of code to setup a good UI in XCode, and you end up hardcoding a lot of values that make things difficult to change later.

Anyway - just my 2c. Good luck!

Comment: I'd question if it's "reasonable" - while Interface Builder isn't exactly perfect, it saves you from writing a lot of code. There are situations when you are better of creating interfaces in code, but I think defaulting to not using Interface Builder (for the sake of not using IB) is a bad idea.. That said, these resources are equally valid for "where I need to" situations, so +1

Comment: After several months of iPhone programming, I can safely say that not using Interface Builder is the way to go. It really doesn't save you writing much code, there is excellent auto-complete anyways, and I have gained a deeper understanding of the language. I'm really glad I chose to go this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like this: http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/07/10/working-without-a-nib-part-5-open-recent-menu/

Related Question here: [Cocoa without Interface Builder, initialize an instance of app controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622998/cocoa-without-interface-builder-initialize-an-instance-of-app-controller)

And a more iPhone specific tutorial can be found here: http://www.iphonemusings.com/2009/01/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used [iCodeBlog](http://icodeblog.com/category/interface-builder/) for iPhone tutorials. They work pretty good. Here is the Interface builder category

Comment: "Sans" means "without." You pointed to the IB tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this book:

**iPhone SDK Application Development**
By Jonathan Zdziarski

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154059/

All of the examples and explanations are without interface builder.

If you live in a big city (eg San Francisco), work for a big company, or are in university, you may have access to Safari Online. This book is available online there.

Answer (score 0):

"Beginning iPhone 3 Development" really brought me up to speed fast.

http://iphonedevbook.com/

After that, the Apple Guides and class documentation ...

Comment: Yea that book is great, except it too uses Interface builder.