# iPad app UI design questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview

The interface of my iPad app has multiple section boxes (looks similar to this stackoverflow page). I'm new to xcode and iOS programming but have years of web development experience. I would like to know what is the best way to design this.

Should I put everything in one xib file? (section1headerlabel, section1text1,section1text2..)

or should each section be its own xib file? (like server side include in web dev) if so how do I do this?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that if I'm doing complex things, I generally skip Interface Builder all together and create the view hierarchy using code.  I can do better encapsulation this way.

For information on how to do this, check out this q&a: [What's the best tutorial for iPhone development, sans Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015831/whats-the-best-tutorial-for-iphone-development-sans-interface-builder)

Comment: ok then should i have different .m/.h files for each section? or all in one .m/.h file? (and name the variables section1headerlabel, ection1text1,section1text2..) Just trying to make sense of all this from a web dev background.

Comment: Yes, you'd have several .m/.h files implementing subclasses of UIView.  You'd have your main UIView subclass which contains other subclasses of UIView (the logical sections of your application).

So you'd have a MyApplicationView which contains a HeaderSectionView, MainContentView, and a FooterSectionView.  The MainContentView could contain many TopicItemViews that correspond to topics or what have you.

Comment: Thanks you so much. That makes a lot of sense. Could you point me to a tutorial that shows what you just described? loading a subview from a main UIView class programmatically?