# cocoa class init doesn't run

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, init

In a simple test app, it starts and puts up a window but never reaches the init in a class. Debugger Console sits with: `Running… (gdb)`

I have nothing in `UntitledAppDelegate.m` or .h

In an NSObject class "untitled" `init` is declared in untitled.h, and in untitled.m I have

```
 @implementation untitled
   - (id)init {

    if (self = [super init])
    { 
       int i=1;
       i=i++;
       NSLog(@"%i here",i);
    }

    return self;
  }

 @end
```

Breakpoints in UntitledAppDelegate.m show that it reaches the last  }.

Xcode is set for 3.2, OSX 10.6, and garbage collection.

There are no errors or warnings; it runs.,

Why doesn't init run, and how do I fix it?

Comment: show the code where you are initialising untitled class.

Comment: @rishi    at symbols had to be removed in order to add comment-  #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


interface untitled : NSObject {

}
- (id)init ;
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you ever call init for any instance of that class ?
somewhere in your code you should have :

```
untitled *myObj = [[untitled alloc] init];
```

If not, then this is the reason why it is not called.

Comment: I'm following examples from Hillegas' book and Wentk's book, in which they create a class and include a -(id)init. The init runs at startup without any programmed messages sent to it. This succeeded when I created Command Line Tools (no window), but not when I created Cocoa Applications (with a window). It seems like the window opening prevents the startup init. Breakpoints show that untitledAppDelegate runs through but init is never reached.   BTW, an [alloc init] can yield lots of problems when there's a modified init present.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize to all who wasted time looking at the result of my bonehead errors.
Several combined, but mainly I realized that those authors were using an NSView class with initWithFrame, which runs at startup like it should with no additions to  UntitledAppDelegate.

I still haven't figured out why a simple init in an NSObject class doesn't run at startup.

```
- (id)init {  
if (self = [super init]) {  
NSLog(@"Foo");  
}  
return self;  
}
```

Comment: Aha! I think I just found it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622998/cocoa-without-interface-builder-initialize-an-instance-of-app-controller (can't get a new line here) +initialize runs at startup but -init only initializes a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
untitled *object = [untitled new];
```